# YII: Unable to set ID for TbButton?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have a view that generates a button:

```
$view->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'id'         =>   'removeButton',
    'label'      =>  $label,
    'buttonType' => 'ajaxButton', 
  ... etc
```

When the button is generated, and I inspect the code, I see:

```
<button name="yt0" id="yt0" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-loading-text="loading...."  type="button">Add to Cart</button>
```

Why is both the name and id yt0 and not "removeButton" as I've specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
$view->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
  'htmlOptions'   => array('id'=> 'removeButton'),
   etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Full example:

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'buttonType' => 'submit',
    'type' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'primary' : 'info',
    'label' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',
    'loadingText' => 'Saving...',
    'htmlOptions'   => array('tabindex'=>7, 'id'=>'submit-button', 'class'=>'buttonStateful'),
));
?>


<script>
$('.buttonStateful').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading'); // call the loading function
    setTimeout(function() {
        btn.button('reset'); // call the reset function
    }, 3000);
});
<
```